# How to split string in Perl

Tags: perl, path, split

I have a variable that contains path.

```
my $path = '../images/abc.png';
```

I want to split this into 2 path such that:

```
my $directory = '../images';
my $FileName = 'abc.png';
```

How to do that?

Comment: See [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split your input according to the last forward slash character.

```
my $line = "../images/abc.png";
my @abc = split /\/(?=[^\/]*$)/, $line;
print "Directory :\t" .$abc[0]."\n";
print "FileName  :\t" .$abc[1]."\n";
```

**Output:**

```
Directory : ../images
FileName  : abc.png
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd better use the core module [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;
use File::Basename;

my $path = '../images/abc.png';
my($filename, $dirs) = fileparse($path);
say $dirs,"\t",$filename
```

**output:**

```
../images/    abc.png
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a regular expression

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $path = '../images/abc.png';

my ($dir, $file) = $path =~ m|(.+)/(.*)|;

say for $dir, $file;
```

#### output

```
../images
abc.png
```